# Latitude Longitude not appearing

Tags: android, location, latitude-longitude

I have the following function for retrieving latitude and longitude of the current location of the mobile.

```
  private void getLocation() {


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
            (MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);

    } else {

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);


        if (location != null) {
            double latti = location.getLatitude();
            double longi = location.getLongitude();
            lattitude = String.valueOf(latti);
            longitude = String.valueOf(longi);

            textView.setText("Your current location is" + "\n" + "Lattitude = " + lattitude
                    + "\n" + "Longitude = " + longitude);

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to Trace your location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

This function is being called through a button. The problem is that by clicking the button the function doesn't seem to find the location and keep on toasting the same message which is toasted in the else statement. Can someone please point out that what is it that i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define a `LocationListener`

```
private final LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
    //your code here to get lat lon from location
}
```

And in the activity

```
mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_REFRESH_TIME,
        LOCATION_REFRESH_DISTANCE, mLocationListener);
```

Comment: then where should i call this onLocationChanged??

Comment: in your onCreate() method